# Twitter Bootstrap 2 Carousel - how to display 4 pictures at a time rather than just 1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

This may not be possible for the carousel but is there a way to display 4 pictures at a time rather than just 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Responded to a question such as this one before, here is the result:

[Twitter Bootstrap 2 carousel - display a set of thumbnails at a time like jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9758836/680398)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/S2rnm/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/S2rnm/).

Comment: Given your example is there any way to maintain the responsiveness of the carousel using multiple images instead of just 1? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518412/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-carousel-with-multiple-items