# Bootstrap thumbnails not appearing in middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I want to use thumbnails in carousel using bootstrap
Found a solution here : [Twitter Bootstrap 2 carousel - display a set of thumbnails at a time like jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745746/twitter-bootstrap-2-carousel-display-a-set-of-thumbnails-at-a-time-like-jcarou)

It works fine , but the horizontal images with height smaller than the div appear to be aligned towards the top. How should I make it appear in the middle... means margin from top and bottom should be same

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`.carousel .item img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}`