# Bootstrap Carousal - Number of pictures

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How we can change number of pictures in the bootstrap carousal.
In following code by default 3 images being displayed which can be scrolled to view others, so instead of 3 I want to change the number to 4 or 5 or 6. How to do this?

Bootstrap carousal. Change default Number of images

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
            interval: false
        });

        // for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
        // Do the same for the next, next item.
        $('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function () {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            if (next.next().length > 0) {
                next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            } else {
                $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
```

It displayed image as below:

[image]
So instead of 3 pictures, I want to display 4 or five pictures, I don't see any setting related to in Script.

Comment: I don't know if it's updated but this was not possible back in bootstrap 2, although this guy had a workaround or sorts ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745746/twitter-bootstrap-2-carousel-display-a-set-of-thumbnails-at-a-time-like-jcarou/9758836#9758836.

Comment: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ this plugin will help you to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

without using jquery try adding tk ol carousel indicator

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>Use Bootstrap s carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>        
      </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please you can try this and see bootplay link:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/54EC1oETAm